# How to filter an object array with multiple parameters?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm having an array with employees containing all data of the employees.

**example of 1 employee in the list:**

```
accountActive: false
companynr: 0
email: "aart.versendaal@technomanage.nl"
id: 100
photoURL: "http://technet/employeephoto/anonymous.jpg"
staffnr: 0
tla: "FIS"
userName: "Firstname Surname"
workPlace: "999"
```

With the following code to show the search results.
*(only show the name and a photo)*

```
<div class="result" ng-repeat="employee in data | limitTo:showLimit">
    <div class="result_wrapper">
        <div class="result_name">{{employee.userName}}</div>
        <div class="result_image">
            <img ng-src="{{employee.photoURL}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this login_controller

```
var employees; //list of all employees
$scope.data = []; //the filtered employees
$scope.showLimit = 5;

//The filter I made (no input = no results)
$scope.getData = function (query) {
    if (query.length === 0) {
        $scope.data = [];
    } else {
        $scope.data = $filter('filter')(employees, query);
    }
};
```

now I want to filter on multiple params of an employee (e.g. userName and tla). When one of the 2 params is equal to the query, it must be in the $scope.data (just like a || ).
I want to do this in my getData() function so I can manipulate some things when certen query input is given.

I was thinking about something like:

```
$scope.data = $filter('filter')(employees, {'userName': query || 'tla': query});
```

But that just wont work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're going to have to write your own function to filter the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jason Goemaat for pointing me out in what direction I had to go

Controller:

```
var employees; //list of all employees
$scope.data = []; //the filtered employees
$scope.showLimit = 5;

//The filter I made (no input = no results)
$scope.getData = function (query) {
    if (query.length === 0) {
        $scope.data = [];
    } else {
        $scope.data = $filter('employeeLogin')(employees, query);
    }
};
```

Filter:

```
app.module.filter('employeeLogin', function () {
    return function (employees, query) {
        var results = [];
        var q = query.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(employees, function (employee) {
            if (employee.userName.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1) {
                results.push(employee);
            } else if (employee.tla.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1) {
                results.push(employee);
            }
        });
        return results;
    };
});
```